# Evaluation of $\int \frac{x\sin( \sqrt{ax^2+bx+c})}{ax^2+bx+c} \ dx\ $

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

How do we find $$\int  \frac{x\sin( \sqrt{ax^2+bx+c})}{ax^2+bx+c} \ dx\  $$

NB: It is not mandatory that $ax^2+bx+c$ has    only a single root

Comment: What makes you think this has a closed form? Where is this integral from?

Comment: Start  writing with $x=\frac{2ax+b-b}{2a}$

Comment: Maybe Euler's substitution works

Comment: Try this; $$\int \frac{x\sin( \sqrt{ax^2+bx+c})}{ax^2+bx+c} \ dx= \int \frac{x\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k (c+x (b+a x))^{1+2 k}}{(1+2 k)!}}{{ax^2+bx+c}}$$ and integrate term by term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$\int\dfrac{x\sin\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}}{ax^2+bx+c}dx$

$=\int\dfrac{x}{ax^2+bx+c}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(ax^2+bx+c)^{n+\frac{1}{2}}}{(2n+1)!}dx$

$=\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^nx(ax^2+bx+c)^{n-\frac{1}{2}}}{(2n+1)!}dx$

Answer (score 2):

**Too long for a comment:**

If the polynomial has only a single root, i.e $ax^2+bx+c=A^2(x+B)^2$, the integral may be solved by substitution $y=A(x+B)$. The result is then a straightforward combination of the trigonometric integrals:
$$\frac{B}{A}\left(\text{sinc}(y)-\text{Ci}(y)\right)+\frac{1}{A^2}\text{Si}(y)$$
I don't quite see how the non-degenerate case can be solved in closed form, though an approximation can be derived by expanding $\sin$ in a Taylor series, and then using Euler's substitution on each of the rational fractions in $\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}$.